# Simulating for loop 100 times with a matrix

Tags: python, finance

I am currently trying to run a simulation of MBS a 100 times. I have written the for loop that I need, however I need to make this loop run 100 times. After consulting with a friend, I believe that I need to specify the "size" parameter in np.random.normal as a matrix, however my coding skills are limited and I would greatly appreciate your help with doing so. Specifically, for a sequence of correlation parameter ρ (rho) between 0 and 1, I need to simulate 100 MBSs, and report the average payoff of each tranche across the simulations Below is my code with notes.

EDIT:
I appreciate the code proposed in the answers and it is indeed very useful. I have one last hurdle now to include: How do I include a payment structure that is sequential. Specifically, The junior tranche is the first to absorb losses from the
underlying collateral pool and does so until the portfolio loss exceeds 5% (i.e. the proportion of defaults exceeds 10%) at which point the junior tranche becomes worthless. The mezzanine
tranche begins to absorb losses once the portfolio loss exceeds 5% and continues to do so until the portfolio loss reaches 10% (i.e. the proportion of defaults exceeds 20%). Finally, the senior
tranche absorbs portfolio losses in excess of 10%. As of now we've only considered an average payoff given a specific share of the total payoff.

```
rho_list = [0,0.2, 0.5,0.6, 1] 

# parameters 
n_borrowers = 10
payoff_default = 0.5
payoff_nodefault = 1
threshold = -1.65

# draw of income shocks (I have to draw new values of s and eps for each simulation)
s = np.random.normal(0,1,size=1) # common s for all borrowers
eps = np.random.normal(0,1,size=n_borrowers) # each borrower has their own eps

for rho in rho_list :

  # compute the borrower's income
  x = np.sqrt(rho) * s + np.sqrt(1-rho) * eps

  # which borrower defaults?
  loan_payoff = (x < threshold) * payoff_default + (x >= threshold) * payoff_nodefault

  # total pool 
  total_payoff = np.sum(loan_payoff)

  # how much does each investor receive from total_payoff?
  senior_payoff = 0.82 * total_payoff 
  mezz_payoff = 0.12 * total_payoff 
  junior_payoff = 0.6 * total_payoff 

  print('total: {}, senior: {}, mezz: {}, junior: {}'.format(total_payoff, senior_payoff, mezz_payoff, junior_payoff))

# next steps (this is what I need help with)
# repeat this for 100 simulations and compute the average payoff to each investor
# is it possible to generate the income for all simulations in one step? 
# Idea: specify the "size" parameter in np.random.normal as a matrix
```

Comment: to run something hundred times you can simply use a `for` loop: `for _ in range(100):`

Comment: Where is `rho_list` defined?

Comment: Updated with rho_list definition

Comment: for a sequence of correlation parameter ρ (rho) between 0 and 1, I need to 
simulate 100 MBSs, and report the average payoff of each tranche across the simulations

Comment: Have you looked at `pymbs` ? https://pypi.org/project/pymbs/ , its designed specifically for mbs modeling.

Comment: So 100 simulations where `s` and `eps` are new on each simulation, and for each simulation, calculate the payoffs for each rho?

Comment: heads up, junior rate should be 0.06, not 0.6

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain I've understood the problem entirely correctly, but I think this does what you want without using any `for` loops by taking advantage of numpy's broadcasting. I'm by no means an expert in numpy, and multidimensional calculations are something I'm not super comfortable with but I believe my logic is sound. I'd be more than happy for any feedback.

### Solution

```py
# Setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


investors = np.array([0.82, 0.12, 0.06])
rhos = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)[..., None, None]

default = 0.5
nodefault = 1
thresh = -1.65

n_sims = 100
n_borrowers = 10

s = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(1, n_sims, 1))
eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(n_sims, n_borrowers))


# Solution
x = np.sqrt(rhos) * s + np.sqrt(1 - rhos) * eps
payoffs = (x < thresh) * default + (x >= thresh) * nodefault

avgs = payoffs.sum(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
investor_payouts = avgs[..., None] * investors[None, ...]

data = np.hstack([rhos.reshape(-1, 1), investor_payouts])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["rho", "senior", "mezz", "junior"])
```

Output:

```py
    rho  senior    mezz  junior
0   0.0  8.0155  1.1730  0.5865
1   0.1  7.9909  1.1694  0.5847
2   0.2  7.9991  1.1706  0.5853
3   0.3  7.9868  1.1688  0.5844
4   0.4  7.9991  1.1706  0.5853
5   0.5  7.9786  1.1676  0.5838
6   0.6  7.9745  1.1670  0.5835
7   0.7  7.9745  1.1670  0.5835
8   0.8  7.9458  1.1628  0.5814
9   0.9  7.9007  1.1562  0.5781
10  1.0  7.8310  1.1460  0.5730
```

### Rationale

With `n_sims = 100` and `n_borrowers = 10`, and `rhos = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)` we have the shapes

```py
>>> rhos.shape
(11, 1, 1)

>>> s.shape
(1, 100, 1)

>>> eps.shape
(100, 10)
```

The reasoning for the shapes of `rhos` and `s` are so that broadcasting can be done more easily.

For each simulation, we essentially need to calculate the payoffs for each `ρ`. In essence, we want an array of shape `(11, 100, 10)` where along the first axis are the values of `ρ`, and the second and third axis are one hundred simulations of 10 borrowers.

The first term of your equation is `sqrt(ρ) * s`, and we want `(11, 100, 1)` so that we can broadcast later.

```py
np.sqrt(rhos) * s
# shapes (11, 1, 1) * (1, 100, 1) = (11, 100, 1)
```

This gives us the same 100 simulated values for `s`, each multiplied by a different value of `sqrt(ρ)` (e.g., for `ρ=0`, which is the first value in `rhos`, the first row of this `(11, 100)` matrix is all zeros). We've added an extra dimension to get `(11, 100, 1)` in order to add to the second term.

The second term follows a similar logic, we want the values of `sqrt(1 - ρ)` to be multiplied across 100 simulations of 10 borrowers. Since `eps.shape == (100, 10)` and `rhos.shape == (11,)`, and we want `(11, 100, 10)`, we need to add two new axes to `rhos`:

```py
np.sqrt(1 - rhos) * eps
# shapes (11, 1, 1) * (100, 10) = (11, 100, 10)
```

Now we want to combine those two terms for a final array of shape `(11, 100, 10)`. This is why we gave the first term a new axis to get `(11, 100, 1)`, which allows us to broadcast the values of the first term over the second term's last axis:

```py
np.sqrt(rhos) * s + np.sqrt(1 - rhos) * eps
# shapes (11, 100, 1) + (11, 100, 10) = (11, 100, 10)
```

We're doing this because, in your original code, you are taking a scalar `s` and broadcasting it over `eps`, which was an array of length 10. In order to do that, numpy needed to broadcast `s` into an array of shape `(10,)` to match the shape of `eps`. We're doing the same thing here, except we're trying to do it for 100 simulations AND 11 different `ρ` values.

After all that nasty broadcasting, we arrive at an array which we can now collapse into a sum across borrowers, (`total_payoff = np.sum(loan_payoff)` in your original code), and then an average across all 100 simulations, which is achieved by the axis arguments to those respective functions; axis 2 has 10 elements, representing the borrowers; axis 1 has 100 elements, representing each simulation. So we use

```py
payoffs.sum(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
```

Note that the calculation of the intermediary `x` is the same as in your original code.

At this point, we've obtained the average total payoff for 100 simulations across 10 borrowers, for 11 different values of `ρ`. From here we want to break out the average payoff by investor. In other words, we have 11 average payoffs (one for each `ρ`), and 3 investor rates, and we want to broadcast the 3 investor rates over the 11 average payoffs to get an array of shape `(11, 3)`.

Right now `avgs.shape == (11,)` and `investors.shape == (3,)` so we need to add some axes to get our desired result:

```py
investor_payouts = avgs[..., None] * investors[None, ...]
# shapes (11, 1) * (1, 3) = (11, 3)
```

Finally, the `np.hstack` stuff isn't necessary, that's just me stacking the `ρ` values with the results so that I could put everything in a dataframe. You could just as easily create the resultant dataframe in a number of other ways, depending on what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Indeed, it does what I want it to do! I have one final question. Since here we simply assume that the tranche average payoff structure is fixed, how would you solve the issue of sequential payment structures.

Comment: My issue is that to be precise the payment structure is the following: the junior tranche is the first to absorb losses from the underlying collateral pool and does so until the portfolio loss exceeds 5% (i.e. the proportion of defaults exceeds 10%) at which point the junior tranche becomes worthless. The mezzanine tranche begins to absorb losses once the portfolio loss exceeds 5% and continues to do so until the portfolio loss reaches 10% (i.e. the proportion of defaults exceeds 20%). Finally, the senior tranche absorbs portfolio losses in excess of 10%.

Comment: How would you find the average payoff to each tranche given such a payment structure? (sorry for three comments, but my question was too long)